# Access directive scope in transclude content

Tags: angularjs-ng-transclude

I created a directive with transclude feature.I provided the default content in template so user can either provide the customized content or use the default one. In the transclude content, I need access directive scope's function. I found that there is no problem in the default content, but it doesn't work in customized content. Here is the code:

```
<script>
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function () 
{ 
return { 
restrict: 'EA', 
replace: true, 
transclude: {"Result":"?uploaderResult"}, 
controller: function ($scope){ 
$scope.doSth1=function(){} 
$scope.doSth2=function(){} }, 
templateUrl:"template.html" });
</script>
```

and the template.html is

```
<div ng-transclude="Result">
<a ng-click="doSth1()">Default Content</a>
</div>
```

this works as expected. The page consuming the directive:

```
<uploader-result>
<a ng-click="doSth1()">Customized Content</a>
</uploader-result>
```

this doesn't work. I googled and found that I can use $$nextSibling.doSth1(), this is OK. But if doSth1() is called with ng-repeat, it stops working again. I changed it to $parent.$$nextSibling.doSth1(), still not works.

Thanks in advance.